# MySQL2 with native extensions ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to install the **gem mysql2** for **Ruby Enterprise Edition**. I am getting error that says:

```
    Installing mysql2 (0.2.7) with native extensions /Users/rookieRails/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /Users/vinayashrestha/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
```

Does anyone have any idea what configuration options I should use, or whatever I need to to to get this fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized I didn't have mySQL installed, I recently upgraded to Lion, and had forgotten to install mySQL. Still, after that I got some issues, I followed this article to setup everything:

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/8/30/upgrading-to-snow-leopard

And now everything works fine.

Comment: I don't understand why you need mysql installed, you probably connect to a remote server, maybe you mean 'mysql connector'

Answer (score 53):

Try with this, it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Worked for me on a vagrant box running ubuntu.

Comment: what is the windows version of that?

Answer (score 34):

If you're using `rvm`, don't install `libmysql-ruby` because it's related with Ruby included in Ubuntu packages. It should be good enough with:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case only unlinking symlinks and reinstalling mysql in brew helped:

```
brew unlink mysql
brew cleanup
brew install mysql
gem install mysql2
```

Comment: This resolved the issue on osx with homebrew as well as on ubuntu with linuxbrew

Answer (score 2):

For mac user, according to https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1175 , I fixed it by

```sh
gem install mysql2 -- \
 --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.26/lib \
 --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.26 \
 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.26/bin/mysql_config \
 --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.26/include
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

or

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have to post this and I have to tell people to spread it around.

If you're trying to use mysql as your database, you have done everything right and everything wrong and it simply doesnt work and you keep getting "install activerecord-mysql-adapter".

Just please try putting '' around mysql on the database file.

```
adapter: 'mysql'
```

It took around 5 hours of my life, dll files, messing with adapter files, updating bundle, uninstalling lots of things, reinstalling them... and then "let me put these '' here..."

It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions in http://simplesideias.com.br/instalando-o-ruby-dois-ponto-zero-no-ubuntu:

```
$ wget -O - http://apt.hellobits.com/hellobits.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ echo 'deb http://apt.hellobits.com/ precise main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hellobits.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-ni
```